# How Do You Parse an Array Column in Postgresql Using libpq on Linux

Tags: postgresql, libpq

For basic data types I have no problems parsing data using a format like:

```
  if (FALSE == PQgetisnull(res, rowNumber, columnIndex))
  {
     retVal.m_assignedSocket = atol(PQgetvalue(res, rowNumber, columnIndex));
  } else
  {
     retVal.m_assignedSocket = 0;
  }
```

I would like to have an array field in one of my tables that is an array of bigints.  I believe I can insert the data like this:

```
  // array elements are separated by curly braces
  insertQuery += "{";

  for (size_t i = 0; i < settings.m_stepVector.size(); i++)
  {
     if (snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), ", %llu", settings.m_stepVector[i]) > (int) sizeof(buffer))
     {
        LOG_SYSTEM_WARNING("Unexpected string truncation\n");
     }
     insertQuery += buffer;
  }

  insertQuery += "}";
```

The problem comes with parsing the row.  I have not found any examples or documentation stating the format of the returned array column.  My assumption is that it is a string with curly braces on each end.  What is the format between the curly braces?  It doesn't seem like this is something new but I cannot find an answer anywhere.  Could be I don't know the right keywords to search under.  I tried postgresql, array, PQgetvalue, and parsing.

Comment: I have seen two libraries posted online, libpqxx and libpqtypes, that may offer a solution.  I am not familiar with either.  The original code base was written in c but new code being added is c++.

Comment: Did some experiments with libqpxx.  I see that I can cast the field as an array but that puts it into an array parser object.  It looks like the array is iterated over using a get_next method.  The value will be a string that will need to be converted to the expected numeric data type I would assume.  Not sure if the as<ULONG64>() will work here or if I need to use atoll().

Answer (score 1):

Final experiments show this to be working:

```
  retVal.m_rules.clear();
  pqxx::array_parser parser = result[columnIndex].as_array();
  arrayObject obj = parser.get_next();
  while (obj.first != pqxx::array_parser::done)
  {
     if (obj.first == pqxx::array_parser::string_value)
     {
        // arrays return a string value so atoll needed to convert to number
        retVal.m_rules.push_back(atoll(obj.second.c_str()));
     }
     obj = parser.get_next();
  }
  columnIndex++;
```

Result is defined as pqxx::result::iterator &result.